# Maximum and minimum of function of two variables on the set $M=\left\{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2 \ \Bigl|\ x+y\leq L\right\}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Find the points of maximum and absolute minimum of the following function 
of two variables
$$f(x,y)=\frac{\cosh (x-y)}{x}\left(e^{x}-x-1\right)$$
on the set:
$$M=\left\{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2 \ \Bigl|\ x+y\leq L\right\}$$
Let us initially extreme points internal to M, ie
$$int(M)=\left\{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2 \ \Bigl|\ x+y< L\right\}$$
and is simple to verify that $(0,0)$ is a saddle point.

For the extreme point in the boundary of M:
$$\partial M=\left\{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2 \ \Bigl|\ x+y = L\right\}$$
we apply the Lagrange multiplier method. Is correct the procedure?

Now I get some equations that (in my opinion) are impossible to solve in closed form. Or not?

What do you think?

Comment: I would study the extrema of the function $g(x)=f(x, -x+L)$ and then classify them w.r.t. $f$.